# How to ensure the latest version of website is shown on computers with the site cached?

Tags: html, caching

I have a basic website that is mainly html with a small amount of JS to open and close sections of the page on button clicks.

I need to ensure that the details on the page is always upto date, but currently when I make a change to the HTML, and then go back to the site, it shows the old data unless I press ctrl + shift + r to force a refresh.

From research online I have added a meta tag,

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store"/>
```

Which I believe should stop any data being stored in cache
[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

Currently though when I make an update and push to GitHub (GitHub pages website) it doesnt show straight away if I load the webpage on a computer that has previously accessed the website, then it still shows the previous version. Is there anything else I can do to ensure it updates as soon as the code is update on GitHub?

Comment: The best way to do it, is to add a query string fetching last updated data of the JS or CSS files. E.g. `<Filepath>?updated=07112022` So whenever the files are updated, technically it will be a new URL and will load from the server and not from the cache.
Another way is to add versioning to the files.

Comment: Hi, yeh I have versioning in my sw.js file `const TGAbxApp = "TG-ABX-App-v1.1.16"` the website can also be installed as a web app. But I didnt think this would affect the loading of the website, just if a user opened the web app.

Answer (score 0):

The meta not really working.

Small changes, too small changes and mainly in css or js imported, are not to enough for the browser to consider it has to reload entirely.

If you import js file

```
<script src="XXXXXX.js"></script>
```

You can change the version

```
<script src="XXXXXX.js?version = 0.67"></script>
```

next you put 0.68, and so on

browser see the version change and reload